# How to calculate same value counts for each column (all columns values are numeric) is less than 40% of that column in a dataset in R

Tags: r, count, unique, sapply

In R code, I want to select all the variables from a dataset where same value occurs for each column is less than 40% for that column.
I am appling the sapply, but not getting the correct output. 
Note: All the columns values are numeric.

```
train = train[, sapply(train, function(col) length(unique(col))) < 0.4*nrow(train)]
```

Please suggest how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By playing around with a toy dataset, I found this code that works

```
train[, sapply(train, function(x) {(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)/nrow(train))[[1]] < 0.4})]
```

Basically, I create the table of relative frequencies (sorted in decreasing order) for each numeric column in `train`, and then I check whether the most frequent value for each column occurs less than 40% of the times. If yes, this column is selected, otherwise discarded.

Comment: Hi Ric, thank you for your reply. Just required one more help, in the above code if I don't want to remove a particular column (say "TARGET"), how to do that?

Comment: @Goutam You can just add it again later on, after you performed the selection

Comment: Thanks @Ric, for your reply!

Comment: @Goutam You're welcome! If you found my answer useful you could consider accepting it maybe